# Setup .gitignore for ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, dll, gitignore

I tried to setup a `.gitignore` for ASP.NET project but it does not work.

I did this example: [.Gitignore for ASP.NET](https://gist.github.com/indyfromoz/4109296)

What can I do that in a commit it will not pass unnecessary files like ddl, cache, etc.?

Comment: Rather than link to a gist, please paste the `.gitignore` file you are using as part of the question

Comment: Did you rename the file after download to `.gitignore`? or is it still called `aspnet-mvc.gitignore`?

Comment: @Smartis I called it .gitignore

Comment: try to use this [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io)

Comment: @neelsg I can't add file to question. But I using 100% code from link which I add to question

Answer (score 7):

You can use your terminal to add a gitignore file.Once your on the directory of your project, type the command `dotnet new gitignore`

Comment: I'd like to iterate that the above answer is, in my opinion correct, but should be better iterated upon. This is to be done within the Package Manager Console which can be opened through the Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Package Manager Console menu and typing in dotnet new gitignore. To ensure proper installation be sure to check all files that need to be ignored are no longer visible when using the "git status" command from either the GUI or git cmd